# Passing query string parameters to Flash

Tags: html, flash, url, parameters

I've looked into this and there's a lot of ways to achieve this (JS, Asp, PHP) but I'm not well versed in any of them and I haven't managed to get this to work properly.

I have a website, and I want people to access an embedded Flash document in it, `Main.swf`, where parameters in the URL affect the content of the document.

I can easily set this up in this way:

```
http://www.website.com/Main.swf?hello=world
```

But what I really want is the clean look of:

```
http://www.website.com/?hello=world
```

Here's my full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Main</title>
            <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
            body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
            #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="flashContent">
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" id="Main" style="float: none; vertical-align:middle">
                    <param name="movie" value="Main.swf?update=0.0.0.12" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                </object>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```